# Relational interpretation and 'simulated universe'

Tags: quantum-interpretations

With a [relational interpretation of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics), like Rovelli's, does the unverifiable simulated universe fear fall apart? Given that there are no entities 'plugged in' from the outset - no entities that are intrinsically un-observable - wouldn't that simulation be no different from their actual experience?

Comment: No, it does not. If the observed laws are simulated then no inference can be made about the laws governing the simulator. Therefore, relational interpretation may itself be an artifact of the simulation.

Comment: But if relational QM does away with the notion of absolute state for systems, deriving all properties from interactions, then given this is what is observed (if properties independent of observation are not necessary to fit observed data), how would a simulation of such a QM system fundamentally differ from an 'actual' QM system?

Comment: The conceptual schemes we employ to describe fundamental or any other differences simply would not apply, we could not even conceive what the simulator is, let alone describe the differences.